# Errors when booting Ubuntu from Live USB

Tags: boot, live-usb, 17.04, acpi, nouveau

I am trying to format my machine and installing fresh copy of Ubuntu 17.04. When I try to boot into the Live USB I get several errors on the screen and the process stops before I the boot finishes. Has anyone seen these errors before and know what is causing them and how to solve this issue? I have very limited experience of Linux so I have no idea what is causing this.

[image: See error messages here]

Comment: If I remember correctly, `nouveau` is a driver for nvidia graphics chips/cards. So I suspect that there are problems with the graphics. It may help to add the boot option `nomodeset`. See this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and links from it.

Comment: You are welcome :-) Now that we know that it works, I will convert it to an 'answer', which makes it easier for other users with the same problem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems with the driver for the graphics chip/card: `nomodeset`

If I remember correctly, `nouveau` is a driver for nvidia graphics chips/cards. So I suspect that there are problems with the graphics.

It often helps in helps to add the boot option `nomodeset`, when there are problems with nvidia and/or amd-ati-radeon graphics. See the following link, and links from it,

[Boot options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)

### Next (maybe): proprietary driver

Next, after the installation and the fix with `nomodeset`, you can install a proprietary driver. If you find such a driver that works well, you will be able to use the 'full power' of the graphics card. It can be tricky to test and find a driver that works well, so if the computer works fairly well now, you need not try this next step.